# Natural deduction proof of $p \lor (p\implies q)$ with propositional calculus

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I'm having a bit of trouble proving this with the propositional calculus rules. 
$$p \lor (p\implies q)$$
Would someone mind helping me and showing which rules they've used with an explanation! Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to prove this using a formal proof system?  If so, what are the rules for this system?  A truth-table would be really easy: is that allowed? And if you can be more informal, think about this: $p$ is either True or False. What happens in either case to the statement as a whole?

Comment: What have you tried, and where exactly did you get stuck? Potential answerers will be much more willing and able to help you if your question is not just "Please do my homework for me".

Comment: I need to solve it using propositional calculus (or-I, or-E, and-I, and-E, not-I, not-E, -> I, -> E, PC and LEM). I tried assuming -(p v (p -> q)) and got stuck with deriving q to get p -> q

Comment: Then show us what you got so far and we will help you fill in the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $p$.$\;$Then we get

- $p$$\\[4pt]$

  $p\lor (p\rightarrow q)$

Next, assume $\lnot p$.$\;$Then we get

- $\lnot p$$\\[4pt]$

  $\lnot p \lor q$$\\[4pt]$

  $p\rightarrow q$$\\[4pt]$

  $p\lor (p\rightarrow q)$

In either case, we have $p\lor (p\rightarrow q)$.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas with a disjunction as the main connective are often a bit difficult to derive, if the last step was not simply weakening by $\lor I$. You could try the following stategy:

Base your proof on an analysis by cases -- that is, apply as the final step $\lor E$ -- on $p \lor \neg p$. The formula $p \lor \neg p$ is itself derivable in natural deduction (though a bit difficult as well).
For the case with assumption $p$, you can derive $p \lor (p \to q)$ in one step by application of $\lor I$.
For the case with assumption $\neg p$, derive $p \to q$ via the formula $\neg p \lor q$ obtained in a similar manner.
The proof skeleton then looks as follows:

[image]

It now just remains for you to fill in the question marks, that is, the subderivations of $\vdash p \lor \neg p$ and $\neg p \lor q \vdash p \to q$. (Hint: The latter will again end in an $\lor E$ step, with assumptions $\neg p$ and $q$ from which both times you derive $p \to q$).